# How can MSVC6 handle exceptions from extern "C" functions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, exception

I'm working on an application written in Visual Studio 6 (I know, FML) that is calling functions in a DLL using `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`. The newer code can't compile in VC6, and needs a newer compiler. The DLL has a few functions that construct a C++ object, and then the VC6 program uses the object through an abstract class.

This works just fine usually, but it runs into problems when the functions retrieved by `GetProcAddress` throw exceptions -- even when the exceptions are caught within the DLL. I've noticed that this doesn't happen when the abstract class's methods throw an exception. Things work normally in that case.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I make VC6 generate code to handle the exceptions properly?

**Edit**: Here's an example of a function that causes the program to crash:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) Box* getBox(const char* addr)
{
    try {
        return createBox(addr);
    } catch (std::exception& ex) {
        LOG_ERROR("Open failed: " << ex.what());
        return 0;
    } catch (...) {
        LOG_ERROR("Error while opening.");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are all modules using the same instance of the msvc runtime?

Comment: They are not and that's the problem.

Comment: @Brian Do you have catch all handlers in the DLL? Can we see an example of one such handler that doesn't catch an exception.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I posted an example above. You'll notice that there is a catch-all handler. It doesn't matter whether this is present or not.

Comment: I assume migrating to a newer VC++ version is not an option? :(

Comment: That looks like a bug to me, unless `LOG_ERROR`, `<<` or `ex.what()` are raising.

Comment: What exception settings (the compiler option starting with `/EH`) are you using?  Do you have any callbacks, where a function pointer is used to call the VC6 code from the DLL?  Are exceptions expected to propagate through any callbacks?

Comment: @BenVoigt Originally I had the DLL compiling with /EHsc. I tried /EHa, but that didn't fix things, so I went back to /EHsc. The VC6 app is compiled with /GX

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution or workaround for this? Do you think that upgrading to VS2012 would fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do inheritance cross compiler versions like that. It almost works but exceptions and a few other things go crazy.

Comment: and that's why I always say that if your dll is going to live long, you should limit the public interface to C, not C++.

Comment: The problem here isn't in the interface. The problem is that exceptions _internal to the DLL_ are causing the program to abort before the exceptions are caught. The exceptions aren't meant to cross the DLL boundary, they're to be thrown and caught entirely within the DLL code.

Comment: The problem is the ABI compatibility has been broken in a way that's confusing the runtime.